# I am trying to get gestures in here mobile sdk but didn't understand what to pass to gestures method? How to solve this

Tags: java, android, maps, here-api

I didn't understand what to send to the myongesturelistner class, but still showing an error.

this here shows that this will work

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/dev_guide/topics/map-gestures.html

But getting an error on this part

```
mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(new MyOnGestureListner());
```

error

```
E:\Harsha\DIsha\app\src\main\java\com\example\disha\MainActivity.java:106: error: method addOnGestureListener in interface MapGesture cannot be applied to given types;
                        mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(new MyOnGestureListner());
                                                   ^
  required: OnGestureListener,int,boolean
  found: MyOnGestureListner
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
                    if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                        // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                        map = mapFragment.getMap();
                        // Set the map center to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                        map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0),
                                Map.Animation.NONE);
                        // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                        map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                        mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(new MyOnGestureListner());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
                    }
```

MyOnGestureListner

```
import android.graphics.PointF;


import com.here.android.mpa.common.ViewObject;
import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapGesture;

import java.util.List;

public class MyOnGestureListner implements MapGesture.OnGestureListener {


    @Override
    public MyOnGestureListner() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPanStart() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPanEnd() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMultiFingerManipulationStart() {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mapFragment.getMapGesture().addOnGestureListener(new MyOnGestureListner());
addOnGestureListener() Has three arguments (gesturelistener,100,true);

gesture listener-your gesture
100- your priority
true/false-synchronous/asynchronous